# How can I get my program to pick up application-scoped resources defined in my Application.Resources during design time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, design-time

Application-scoped resources are not being picked up during design time.

I have my App.xaml (renamed 'Program.xaml') populated with a reference to my resource dictionary -

```
<Application
    x:Class="OffendingProgram.Program"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:PersonAI"
    StartupUri="AIAdventure.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Controls/OffendingDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have defined my resource dictionary within a 'Controls' folder with the following -

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ControlTemplate
        x:Key="OffendingTemplate"
        TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}" />
    <Style
        x:Key="{x:Type RepeatButton}"
        TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OffendingTemplate}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have my Main Window set up as follows -

```
<Window x:Class="OffendingProgram.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OffendingProgram"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="Black">
    <RepeatButton />
</Window>
```

During design-time, I can see my 'RepeatButton' occupying the full window (I set the window background to black just to be sure). Yet during run-time, the button vanishes (as expected, since it's picking up an implicit style setting the control template to an empty template).

This is just a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example meant to demonstrate my issue - that the resources are not being applied during design time.

What am I missing to make my resources get picked up during design-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Though the approach may vary based on the version of Visual Studios one is using.

1. Edit your Project File
2. For VS2022, Add the following -

   ```
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml">
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
            <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
   ```

where `Include="..."` paths to your `DesignTimeResources.xaml` file.

3. Reload your project.

Any resource dictionary included within the MergedDictionaries property of the ResourceDictionary defined therein will be picked up and utilized during Design Time.